# Python: How can one process wait for a fifo to be created by another process?

Tags: python, unix, operating-system, fifo

I have two separate python scripts which both create one `fifo` in write mode in random point of time and open `fifo` belonging to one-another in read mode. (i.e, P1 opens fifo1 in write mode, p2 opens fifo2 in write mode. Then p1 opens fifo2 in read mode and p2 opens fifo1 in read mode). Is there a way, that p1 must wait untill fifo2 is created and ready, in case some how p2 has delayed creating fifo2 ?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want the technique so that P1 will wait (differ its exicution) untill P2 creates fifo2. Once it is done, P1 opens fifo2 in read mode and continues usual execution.

Comment: Rather than waiting for the fifo to be created, you should block on the read.  That is, create both fifos early (even before either process starts) and just read from the fifo.  The read will block until data is available.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the technique so that P1 will wait (differ its exicution)
>   untill P2 creates fifo2.

```
import time
while True:
    try:
        fifo2 = open('fifo2', 'r')
        break
    except IOError:
        time.sleep(1)
```